# Can some one identify this plant with really sweet smelling flowers?

Tags: species-identification, plant-anatomy

[image]

Could someone help identifying this plant? 
The flowers on it have a very sweet smell, similar to the night queen.

Comment: Could you add the locale?

Comment: Does it have square stems? If it does then it appears to be mint. If doesn't... I don't know :)

Comment: @ sanjukta - This was in Singapore

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a [buddleia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddleja) of some kind, perhaps Buddliea davidii:

[image]

You can see the flower is tubular and has four 'petals' at the end. They also have paired leaves, the underside of which is lighter than the top.

[image]

> The flowers are generally rich in nectar and often strongly honey-scented.

I never thought it smelled like honey, but it does have a very pleasant and strong sweet smell.

It is present on four continents.